# SVG pattern didn't work with firefox and working with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, design-patterns, svg, adobe-illustrator

SVG file which contain pattern. I don't get the expected result when i open this SVG in Firefox although its works normally on Google chrome.

and here is the code:

```
<pattern  x="-195.767" y="505.764" width="42.226" height="42.227" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="SVGID_1_" viewBox="0.147 -42.227 42.226 42.227" overflow="visible">
<g>
    <polygon fill="none" points="0.147,0 42.373,0 42.373,-42.227 0.147,-42.227      "/>
    <g>
        <polygon fill="none" points="0.147,-42.227 0.147,0 42.373,0 42.373,-42.227          "/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#7F7F7F" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="-40.115" x2="42.52" y2="-40.115"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#7F7F7F" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="-31.67" x2="42.52" y2="-31.67"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#7F7F7F" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="-23.225" x2="42.52" y2="-23.225"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#7F7F7F" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="-14.779" x2="42.52" y2="-14.779"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#7F7F7F" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="-6.334" x2="42.52" y2="-6.334"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#7F7F7F" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="-35.893" x2="42.52" y2="-35.893"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#7F7F7F" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="-27.448" x2="42.52" y2="-27.448"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#7F7F7F" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="-19.002" x2="42.52" y2="-19.002"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#7F7F7F" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="-10.557" x2="42.52" y2="-10.557"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#7F7F7F" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="-2.111" x2="42.52" y2="-2.111"/>
    </g>
</g>
```

```
<pattern  id="SVGID_2_" xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" patternTransform="matrix(1.366 -1.366 -1.366 -1.366 5463.3882 -24086.0156)">
</pattern>

    <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M219.217,110.146c0-59.729-48.405-108.133-108.133-108.133C51.355,2.013,2.949,50.418,2.949,110.146
    c0,59.611,48.406,108.133,108.135,108.133C170.812,218.279,219.217,169.759,219.217,110.146L219.217,110.146z"/>
```

Am I do something wrong or this is a bug in firefox. could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your first pattern block is missing a closing `</pattern>` but I am not sure if that is a copy / paste error.

Can you make the file available online as then we could probably help you further.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the file but somebody else should probably take a look.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y46px/1/

Comment: That's what will gonna make me crazy .. I think the pattern is right but I don't know the issue
Here is a screenshot can describe what I faced::
www.mediafire.com/view/myfiles/#5ou9wkt632hjynx

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25577973/3991783), where a pattern showed up when our web site (actually `localhost:3000`) was viewed with Chrome but not Firefox or Safari.  The strange thing is, I was able to make it work fine on all browsers with a small local {{file:}} test case, but not if the URL said {{http:}}.  And I could break the {{file:}} test case by adding a {{}}.

So all the evidence points to Safari not correctly resolving `url(#SVGID_2_)` as a reference to an id defined within the same file in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in Firefox it is necessary that the pattern is rendered **before** the code that uses it.

I don't know what technologies you use, but when using React, the component with the patterns must be rendered before the component that uses this pattern is rendered.