# SVG fill pattern using a reference to a definition in a file

Tags: html, css, svg

The following attempt to make a rectangle with a pattern fill doesn't seem to work in Safari 6.1, Firefox 30, or Chrome 36, even though the W3 spec [seems to say](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#IRIforms) that a I can use a [non-local IRI reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermNonLocalIRIReference), including a relative one, like `fill="url(localURL.svg#MyId)"`.

### `test.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .patterned { fill: url("patterns.svg#polkadot");
                     stroke: lime; stroke-width: 5px}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
 <svg width="500" height="500">
     <rect class="patterned" height="27" width="58">
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

### `patterns.svg`

```
<svg xml:space="preserve" width="225" height="110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="polkadot" patternunits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20">
            <circle r="10" cx=12 cy=10 fill="purple">
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Safari and Chrome show a black-filled green-outlined rectangle.  Firefox shows an empty or white-filled  green-outlined rectangle.  None of them show the pattern of purple circles.

---

I'm trying this approach because I couldn't get an SVG fill pattern to work on Safari in the Backbone+JQuery+D3 project I'm working on using [the most common method, an inline `defs` with `fill="url(#MyId)"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13069446/3991783).  I couldn't get that approach to fail as a simple test case -- [I thought I had](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25577973/3991783), but that turned out to be a different Safari bug with an obvious workaround.  At least that approach worked in some browsers.

Comment: Two and a half years later... yes this is still broken.  I suspect that Chrome has *no intention* to fix this bug. Of course it works fine if you put all the SVG into a single file... which is faster at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You've a load of syntax errors in your patterns.svg file. Missing " characters round attribute values, an unclosed circle element, patternunits instead of patternUnits.

SVG standalone must be valid XML, it's not as forgiving as html and it's case sensitive on attribute names too. If you loaded the patterns.svg file directly, browsers would tell you all these things.

With all this fixed (as below) this works in Firefox. I'm not sure Chrome/Webkit have implemented this yet.

```
<svg xml:space="preserve" width="225" height="110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="polkadot" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20">
            <circle r="10" cx="12" cy="10" fill="purple"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: With your fixes, it does work on Firefox, but not on Chrome or Safari.  I need it to work on all three, especially Safari, so it's unfortunate that this part of the spec is apparently not supported yet.  Does anyone know otherwise?

Comment: Firefox rocks! it implements a big part of the SVG spec. Too bad is loosing market share ...