# How to set SVG fill using pattern in a different SVG file

Tags: svg, uri

Can anyone please give me a working example of SVG using **non-local URI**?  I tried in [my plunker,](http://plnkr.co/edit/ay9FZyXhNPMQnasHGgHo?p=preview) but it failed. (see fig2 works, but fig1 does not).

I tried this all in one file:

```
<svg>
   <pattern id="hatch2" width="30" height="30" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" transform="scale(20)">
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="30" y2="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
    </pattern>
</svg>

<style>
  .fig2 {  fill: url('#hatch2'); }
</style>

<svg version="1.0" width="286px" height="218px" viewBox="0 0 1430 1090" >
  <path class="fig2" d="M344 582 c-81 -53 -112 -87 -153 -168 -65 -129 -51 -187 51 -210 29 -7 87 -22 128 -34 41 -12 112 -24 158 -27 l82 -6 -6 34 c-4 21 -23 52 -50 79 -35 37 -44 53 -44 81 0 29 -10 47 -51 94 -45 51 -50 63 -46 91 5 31 -11 95 -23 93 -3 0 -23 -12 -46 -27z" stroke="red" />
</svg>
```

and it works, but when I move the `hatch2`to a different file, then it does not work, and I tried **many** ways to format the URL.

Comment: Works fine for me on Firefox.

Comment: Sadly, i was afraid of that.  Seems that this is simply a bug in chrome and safari (and all other browsers except firefox). see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676712/svg-fill-pattern-using-a-reference-to-a-definition-in-a-file